# glsify - error 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type'?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Ok Im following https://tympanus.net/codrops/2019/01/17/interactive-particles-with-three-js/ just trying to get his custom shader to work. I brought in the .frag and .vert files (included in the link) and copied how his setup. When I run I get the error

> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (3:10) You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.

Here:

```
  const material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({ 
    uniforms,
    vertexShader: glslify(require('./vendor/shaders/particle.vert')), //HERE!!!!
    fragmentShader: glslify(require('./vendor/shaders/particle.frag')),
    depthTest: false, //change later?
    transparent: true,
    // blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending
  });

  const geometry = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

// positions
const positions = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(4 * 3), 3);
positions.setXYZ(0, -0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
positions.setXYZ(1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
positions.setXYZ(2, -0.5, -0.5, 0.0);
positions.setXYZ(3, 0.5, -0.5, 0.0);
geometry.addAttribute('position', positions);

// uvs
const uvs = new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Float32Array(4 * 2), 2);
uvs.setXYZ(0, 0.0, 0.0);
uvs.setXYZ(1, 1.0, 0.0);
uvs.setXYZ(2, 0.0, 1.0);
uvs.setXYZ(3, 1.0, 1.0);
geometry.addAttribute('uv', uvs);

// index
geometry.setIndex(new THREE.BufferAttribute(new Uint16Array([ 0, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1 ]), 1));

this.object3D = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
this.scene.add(this.object3D);
```

The path is correct. As an alternate route I tried sticking the shaders in my html script tags and referencing them like this:

```
vertexShader: glslify(document.getElementById("vertexShader2").textContent),
fragmentShader: glslify(document.getElementById("fragShader2").textContent),
```

but this does not work either. What is wrong here? I copied over any reference to glsify packages in his package.json and ran `npm install` on my project.

How can I copy this shader?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does your webpack config files look like? Based on the error, it seems you might be missing the loaders in the `module.rules` list. Make sure you're including

```
{
    test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
    use: ['glslify-import-loader', 'raw-loader', 'glslify-loader']
},
```

so that Webpack knows how to handle `.frag` and `.vert` files.

Also make sure you have

```
"glslify": "^6.2.1",
"glslify-import-loader": "^0.1.2",
"glslify-loader": "^1.0.2",
"raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
```

in `devDependencies` in your Package.json so you're not missing any dependencies.