# how to use glslify-loader-webpack-plugin in laravel mix

Tags: javascript, laravel, three.js, glsl, laravel-mix

I'm working on a **THREE.JS** project and I need to work with shaders when I import the file containing the shaders in my JS file:

```
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { TweenMax as TM } from 'gsap';
import vertexShader from './vertexShader.glsl';
import fragmentShader from './fragmentShader.glsl';

export default class Figure { 
    //we create a new class and we pass the scene as a 
    property;

    constructor(scene) {
        this.$image = document.querySelector('.tile__image');
        this.scene = scene;
        this.callback;
    }
    // conti ........
}
```

**I got this error:**

> app.js:66572 Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:12)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
>
> void main() {
>
> | v_uv = uv;
>
> |
>
> at Object../src/vertexShader.glsl (app.js:66572)
>
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>
> at Module../src/Figure.js (app.js:66312)
>
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>
> at Module../src/Scene.js (app.js:66456)
>
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>
> at Module../src/app.js (app.js:66534)
>
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)
>
> at Object.0 (app.js:66583)
>
> at **webpack_require** (app.js:20)

I put this snippet in my **webpack.mix** file:

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
const source = require('raw-loader!glslify-loader!./my-shader.glsl');

mix.js('src/app.js', 'dist/')
    .sass('src/app.scss', 'dist/')
    .webpackConfig({
        module.exports = {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(glsl|frag|vert)$/,
                    exclude: /node_modules/,
                    use: [
                        'raw-loader',
                        {
                            loader: 'glslify-loader',
                            options: {
                                transform: [
                                    ['glslify-hex', { 'option-1': true, 'option-2': 42 }]
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    });
```

but nothing happens what am I missing?

Comment: Have you looked at this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967930/glsify-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type/58984621#58984621 It looks like you're having the same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [glsify - error 'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58967930/glsify-error-you-may-need-an-appropriate-loader-to-handle-this-file-type)

Comment: no It was the previous link that does the job.